# Angular Application stop reload on change

Tags: angular, updates, reload

I have an application where the external json data files may change by an independent API. What I am using for stopping the reload from happening is

`ng serve --live-reload false`

It works fine for the browser; however, in the console the application still does reload. Is there a way to avoid that as well.

Also, is there a way to stop reload for a specific file type?

Comment: Are you doing anything on ngOnChanges life cycle method?

Comment: no, I am using setInterval function and manually checking on the changes

Comment: Alright I think post the code snippet from one of your components that reloads when the external json data changes so it's easier to help pin point the issue.